# Is it possible to make an antenna that's more compact than a split-ring resonator antenna?

Tags: antennas, radio-frequency

I'm aware that a split-ring resonator antenna works efficiently by being half the size of a classic antenna. But is there any design that takes even less space? I have in mind millimeter or micrometer sized antennas that can get 1.8-2.5 ghz signals efficiently or quasi-efficiently. This is for extremely embedded purposes.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Not sure since it also takes into account physics theories. But if that's a better fit feel free to move this question there. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "antenna efficiency". You can get an arbitrarily small antenna to emit an arbitrarily large amount of power, it's just a matter of solving an ever harder impedance matching problem. Since neither your transmitter nor receiver will be micrometer size, to begin with, the quest for ever smaller antennas is, on its face value, questionable.

Comment: @CuriousOne The radiation efficiency of an antenna is the ratio of radiated power divided by the incident power at the antenna's input port. If the antenna is matched at its input port then the *inefficiency* is the dissipated power divided by the incident power. As the antenna gets smaller its inefficiency increases.

Comment: You don't lose that reflected incident power, so you can make the radiated power as large as you like with a matching network. It just becomes ever harder to build such a network. The entire notion makes no sense, whatsoever.